# Современное значение слова "риторика"

Tags: синонимы

Последние несколько лет слово "риторика" стало использоваться не так, как оно объясняется в словарях, например:

- Риторика государственных СМИ
- Патриотическая риторика
- Впрочем, всё сказанное выше ― риторика, эмоции и сплошной субъективизм.
- Официальная советская риторика «равноправия» и «свобод»

Словарное значение слова "риторика" такое:

> **РИТО́РИКА**, и, ж. [< греч. rhētorikē искусство красноречия].1.В античности и в последующие времена: теория и искусство красноречия. 2. перен.Напыщенная, красивая, но малосодержательная речь

Но, как видно ни "искусство красноречия" ни "малосодержательная речь" здесь не подходят. Новое значение по-моему достаточно нейтрально, что-то вроде "высказываемая точка зрения".

Есть ли какой-то аналог этого слова, который употреблялся в подобных случаях прежде?

Comment: Здесь значение как раз является небольшим расширением уже известного: "Произнесение напыщенных речей для воздействия на людей, способ оформления речей для призывов к чему-то". Имеет негативный оттенок, часто используется для указания на то, что власть намеренно пытается воздействовать на сознание населения.

Comment: А в этом отрывке: "Риторика Райкова в отношении "Единой России" была предельно жёсткой: по информации ГАЗЕТЫ, в закрытой для прессы части доклада Райков вообще поставил под сомнение целесообразность нахождения группы "Народный депутат" в центристской четвёрке, если ею будут приниматься решения, противоречащие идеологии Народной партии." Здесь, как мне кажется, риторика не в значении "пустая болтовня".

Comment: "Речи, слова, сказанные по поводу Единой России; то, как они были сказаны и сформулированы". Упор не на *мнение* , а на **то, что человек публично говорит по какой-то теме**. Я всегда воспринимал так.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможно тут происходит калька из английского в дополнение к традиционному значению взаимствованного слова. Посмотрите №3 [в M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rhetoric)

> 3 :  verbal communication :  discourse

Comment: Дискурс - это хороший вариант. А вот как бы это сказали в 90-х, когда слово "риторика" было не таким популярным?

Comment: Наверно, _речь_ лучше всего подходит в такм контексте